# C# LINQ Orderby - How does true/false affect orderby?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, operators

I was studying a bit of LINQ ordering as I have a list of Ids, and I need to order them sequentially. However, there are certain ids that need to take precedence over the standard ordering.

Given this C# code (which can be pasted into [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) to test) the ordering works as I need it to, but I don't understand why a not (`!`) operator on a contains is giving me the correct ordering?

My expected ordering output is (`5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9`).

If I have a [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.110).aspx) in my ordering, shouldn't it give ordering priority to the rows that returned true? Instead it appears to give ordering priority to rows that return false.

```
using System.Linq;
using System;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var numbersToFilterBy = new [] {5, 11, 20};

    var x = new [] {new XClass(){Id = 1}, new XClass(){Id = 9}, new XClass(){Id = 5}, new XClass(){Id = 3}, new XClass(){Id = 4}, new XClass(){Id = 2}, new XClass(){Id = 6}, new XClass(){Id = 8}, new XClass(){Id = 7}};

    var trueData = (from data in x
                   orderby !numbersToFilterBy.Contains(data.Id), data.Id
                    select data).ToList();

    foreach(var item in trueData){
        Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
  }
}

public class XClass{
    public int Id{get;set;}
  }
}
```

What is the explanation as to why this happens?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) method will sort items **in ascending order by default**. Now, given that the numeric representation of a boolean is:

- `false` = 0
- `true` = 1

`false` values will naturally come first. If you want to reverse the order just use the `descending` keyword:

```
var trueData = (from data in x
               orderby numbersToFilterBy.Contains(data.Id) descending, data.Id
                select data).ToList();
```

Comment: In c# booleans don't have a numeric representation. They aren't numbers behind the scenes that we pretend are booleans, they are just booleans. That having been said the logic may well help people remember how the ordering works (and may well be why the design of .net is this way) but it is worth remembering that there is no numeric representation of a bool in .net.

Comment: @Chris But there is a numeric result if you cast the boolean to an integer. Which is still more than some other languages have.

Comment: The line `int test = (int)true;` throws a compiler exception of `Cannot convert type 'bool' to 'int'`. How are you casting without an error?

Comment: @Chris `bool.CompareTo(bool)` returns integer which will then be used when ordering

Comment: @SebastianSchulz: That's not the same as the boolean being an integer. All `CompareTo` methods return an integer. Its just how comparisons work. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx for more details but basically 0 menas they are equal, negative means the instance comes before the parameter and positive means the instance comes after the parameter. The result of `CompareTo` indicates the order, it is not used when ordering (ie it doesn't sort by the result of CompareTo which is what it sounds like you may be suggesting).

Comment: @Chris [`Convert.ToInt32(Boolean)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cew9dz7.aspx) converts `false` to `0` and `true` to `1`.

Comment: @JeanHominal: This is true but the code in that method is completely independant of the code in `Boolean.CompareTo`. It doesn't convert to an integer to do a comparison, it doesn't even care that you could think of a boolean in terms of an integer. It just defines that false comes before true when ordering ascending - no numbers are involved anywhere.

Comment: @Chris At least internally, false == 0 and true == 1. See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs,f1b135ff6c380b37

Comment: @camerondm9: As I seem to be repeating that is different from booleans being the same as integers. That internal number is a) an implementation detail and thus irrelevant to what a boolean actually is b) Only actually used for when you are converting to other datatypes or for the GetHashCode implementation. However much you can draw parallels between boolean values and numbers there is no language level link between them.

Answer (score 34):

Basically, `false` is earlier than `true`... think of them as false=0, true=1. This is in-keeping with the [documentation for `bool.CompareTo(bool)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz786x34(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you want to prioritize "true" values to the start, just use `OrderByDescending` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Ordering isn't about *priority* – it's about *ordinal value*. You're doing an ascending order against a boolean value, and `false` has a lower ordinal value than `true` in that context.

Answer (score 6):

Let me explain this with an example of a `List<bool>`. Consider the following snippet:

```
List<bool> BoolList = new List<bool>() { true, false, false, true };
var opList = BoolList.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

finally the `opList` will have the values as `false`,`false`,`true`,`true` which means false come first when we apply OrderBy over a list of boolean values. This is because false is consider as `0` and true will be `1`.

In your case the list is first sorted as `5,1,9,3,4,2,6,8,7` based on the `orderby !numbersToFilterBy.Contains(data.Id)` then by `data.Id` will gives you the exact result as `5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9`.

If you remove the `!` from the `OrderBy` it gives you the first sort result like `1,9,3,4,2,6,8,7,5` since the condition is true for `5` hence it will come last in the ordering.

Comment: As I said on another answer false is never considered to be 0 and true 1. It has the same results as if they were but its actually just that they defined an ordering on the two boolean values. It might be nitpicking but suggesting that the framework might be converting bools to integers is misleading and no simpler than the true statement that they just defined an ordering. It might help people remember the ordering if they are used to languages that do have conversion between bools and numeric values of course.