# How to foreach over a collection in a specific order?

Tags: c#

Suppose that inside a `List<Contact>` named `contacts` I want to iterate over all of the `Contact` objects - starting with those with the property `Selected` to true.

This is the structure of `Contact`:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

now inside the list I have three contacts, one of these have the property `Selected` true, when I start the iteration:

```
foreach(contact in contacts)
```

I want that the first item in iteration is the contact with property set to true. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: To summarise the comments in the various answers: The OP wants to iterate over ALL the elements, but with the elements with `Selected` set to true ordered before the elements with `Selected` set to false.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - that's your interpretation, it's not mine. OP, I think you should provide a couple of example inputs and outputs.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Waiting for OP to confirm/deny. He really needs to - question is ambiguous to the point of being unanswerable at the moment (hence I have downvoted the question until it's fixed). However, note that for the non-skipping answer the OP says "the answer is good for me, I don't need to skip"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# LINQ Orderby - How does true/false affect orderby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093937/c-sharp-linq-orderby-how-does-true-false-affect-orderby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort your list `contacts` with LINQ `OrderByDescending`:

```
contacts = contacts.OrderByDescending(x => x.Selected).ToList();
```

Comment: Because there's no notion of skipping here. Or, as another interpretation of the question would lead you to suggest, filtering.

Comment: the answer is good for me, I don't need to skip, I just need to start from the item which have the `Selected` as true

Comment: Well this answer suggests, rather than `starting at the item`, you change which item you start with. There's a subtlety. One suggests you leave the collection in tact in it's original order, the other suggests you re-order. What exactly do you want?