# C# - linq order by certains ids (multiple) then order by something else

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
var lotResults = lotTypes.OrderByDescending(x => x.LotTypeId == 14 || x.LotTypeId == 9 || x.LotTypeId == 15).ThenBy(x => x.Position).ToList();
```

What I am trying to do is have the results return in the order of LotTypeId (14, then 9, then 15) after that give me the rest of the data in the order by position.

My problem is my results always display 15, 9, then 14 no matter what order I have those or conditions...how do I get it to be 14, then 9, then 14?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this

```
var lotResults = lotTypes
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LotTypeId == 14)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.LotTypeId == 9)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.LotTypeId == 15)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Position)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Here is an explanation of how this is working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39094084/14072498

Answer (score 3):

A couple of *C# 8* alternatives to the accepted answer using remapping of `LotTypeId`.
With remapping of `LotTypeId` like this:

```
14 -> 1
9 -> 2
15 -> 3
others -> 4
```

we can use a single `OrderBy` for `LotTypeId`.

Inline remapping of `LotTypeId` (least amount of code lines option)

```
var lotResults = lotTypes
    .OrderBy(x => x.LotTypeId switch { 14 => 1, 9 => 2, 15 => 3, _ => 4 })
    .ThenBy(x => x.Position)
    .ToList();
```

Using a method for remapping (for reuse across multiple LINQ-expressions)

```
var lotResults = lotTypes
    .OrderBy(x => RemapLotTypeId(x.LotTypeId))
    .ThenBy(x => x.Position)
    .ToList();

private static int RemapLotTypeId(int lotTypeId) => lotTypeId switch { 14 => 1, 9 => 2, 15 => 3, _ => 4 };
```

When you have like 5+ remappings, you may not want to maintain the mapped values, only the actual keys to look for, which is `14, 9, 15` in this case. This can be solved using a `List`. This mapping will be zero-based: 14 -> 0 ... others -> 3

```
var lotResults = lotTypes
    .OrderBy(x => RemapLotTypeIdUsingList(x.LotTypeId))
    .ThenBy(x => x.Position)
    .ToList();

private static readonly IList<int> LotTypeIds = new List<int> { 14, 9, 15 }.AsReadOnly();

private static int RemapLotTypeIdUsingList(int keyToFind)
{
    var sortKey = LotTypeIds.IndexOf(keyToFind);
    return sortKey < 0 ? LotTypeIds.Count : sortKey;
}
```

All approaches are tested and verified on my computer.